# Add shutdown and restart options to logout confirmation dialog

Tags: unity, 14.04, shutdown, logout, dialog

I would like to have a more comprehensive dialog when I press `CTRL+ALT+DEL`.
Instead of the classic [image]

I'd like to have suspend/reboot/shutdown options too.
It was possible in my previous installation of 14.04, but I can't find how I did it.

Comment: yes, I meant del, now editing question.

Comment: Try this: http://simionbaws.ro/linux/ubuntu-14-04-ctrlaltdel-shutdown-dialog/

Comment: yes, but not exactly...
I would like to have Lock/Log out in that dialog too.

Comment: The last option in that guide (`gnome-session-quit --power-off`) has lock/suspend/reboot/shutdown options, but no logout.